# Laravel 5.2 dynamic database

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and working on an application that manages information on different servers.

To keep the scenario simple: 
A connection ID will be stored in my local database for each "user". When a user logs in I will read a file with the connection information and grab the one matching their ID. 
All of that is the easy part.

Once I have the connection information how do I inject it as another connection in the Laravel Framework?
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research I found that I can modify the config using:

```
Config::set('database.connections.myDB',[
"driver" => "mysql"
    "host" => "XX"
    "port" => "XX"
    "database" => "XX"
    "username" => "XX"
    "password" => "XX"
    "charset" => "utf8"
    "collation" => "utf8_unicode_ci"
    "prefix" => ""
    "strict" => false
    "engine" => null
]);
```